# Unable to compile Crypt::Sodium on CentOS 6

Tags: perl, perl-xs

System installed Perl is version 5.10.1, which I know is old; these are the joys of RHEL-based distributions! I get the same results whether I use `cpan`, or download the module and `make` it:

```
/usr/bin/perl /usr/share/perl5/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/share/perl5/ExtUtils/typemap  Sodium.xs > Sodium.xsc && mv Sodium.xsc Sodium.c
Error: Cannot parse function definition from 'crypto_generichash_state * T_PTRREF' in Sodium.xs, line 715
Error: 'crypto_generichash_state *' not in typemap in Sodium.xs, line 735
Error: 'crypto_generichash_state *' not in typemap in Sodium.xs, line 739
Error: 'crypto_generichash_state *' not in typemap in Sodium.xs, line 748
make: *** [Sodium.c] Error 1
```

The section around [line 715](https://github.com/mgregoro/Crypt-Sodium/blob/master/Sodium.xs#L715) looks like this:

```
TYPEMAP: <<EOT
crypto_generichash_state * T_PTRREF
EOT
```

I assume the "not in typemap" errors are a result of the initial one, but I'm completely inexperienced with how Perl modules are built; I'm not even sure what this XS stuff is. Any suggestions for how to continue?

Comment: [Your chances of success](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Crypt-Sodium+0.11) don't look good.

Comment: but [they look better](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Crypt-Sodium%200.10) if you try to install `Crypt::Sodium 0.10`.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried and it does work ok if I use the code as it existed just before that heredoc block was added. Of course, it's preferable to have an up-to-date build when it comes to security stuff, but RHEL makes that tough sometimes.

Comment: You can always use perlbrew or whatever to setup a local, up-to-date perl installation that you use instead of the system perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of `ExtUtils::ParseXS` that comes stock with Centos 6 does not support  embedded `typemap`. Installing the latest `ExtUtils::ParseXS` and `libsodium` should fix the issue.

From https://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstypemap.html#Anatomy-of-a-typemap:

> Traditionally, typemaps needed to be written to a separate file, conventionally called `typemap` in a CPAN distribution. With ExtUtils::ParseXS (the XS compiler) version 3.12 or better which comes with perl 5.16, typemaps can also be embedded directly into XS code using a HERE-doc like syntax:
>
> ```
> TYPEMAP: <<HERE
> ...
> HERE
> ```
>
> where `HERE` can be replaced by other identifiers like with normal Perl HERE-docs. All details below about the typemap textual format remain valid.

Comment: `cpan install ExtUtils::ParseXS` followed by `cpan install Crypt::Sodium` did it. Thanks.